# Why won't this simple backbone.js application not persist and read to localstorage?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I'm trying to write a simple demo application using backbone.js but am having problems saving using jeromegn's localstorage adapter. I've read his todo demo, and still fail to see what I'm missing. It's probably something simple....

This simple application found at https://github.com/paulspencerwilliams/backbone_tutorial works fine when the collection is just saved in memory, but nothing is written to localstorage.

Any ideas would be gratefully received!!

Comment: It wasn't exactly minimal, but that link was for a sample project on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Backbone.localStorage plugin is a replacement for Backbone.sync, which normally handles fetching and persisting changes to the server. The `sync` method only fires at certain times, such as when the `save` method is called on a model object.

In your sample code, you're adding a model to the `AddressBook` collection, but that doesn't trigger a call to `sync`. If you call `this.addressBook.create(newContact)` from `handleNewContact`, the item shows up in Chrome's localStorage.

```
var AddView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // snip

    handleNewContact: function(data) {
        var inputField = $('input[name=name]');

        var newContact = new Contact;
        newContact.name = inputField.val();
        this.addressBook.create(newContact); // minor tweak here

        inputField.val('');
        router.navigate('', true);
    },

    // snip
});
```

I cleaned up a few other minor issues in the code while I was reading through it, so if this still fails for you let me know. I can send a pull request or something.

Comment: Hey Josh, that seems much better and great explanation. I thought the calls would be implicit as you suggested, I just didn't pick up on the create / add difference. When I add a contact, I know get two  entries in localstorage. One with key of addressBook and one with key addressBook / id for the actual entry. However, when I reload the page, the fetch fails. If you would be happy to help, please issue a pull request by all means. Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Josh, managed to get loading working. The error was two fold. Firstly, the Contact was defined after the AddressBook class, and thus failed to load. Secondly, I was setting properties such as contact.firstname = 'abc' rather than using contact.set('firstname') = 'abc'. If you did have a couple of minutes, I'd be delighted if you could suggest a few improvements on the application, just to improve code quality a little. Cheers for the help again!!

Comment: Turns out `fetch` was failing for me locally as well. The main issue was that you were declaring the `Contact` variable after the `AddressBook` variable, so `addressBook.model` was undefined and `fetch` wasn't able to determine what kind of object it needed to create. I would highly recommend using unminified versions of Backbone and Underscore when you're developing. The libraries are well commented, and it will greatly speed your learning.

Comment: Hah, we were working on this at the same time. :) I also noticed the property setting issue. Sounds like you're learning fast.

Comment: Cheers Josh for the assistance, it's pretty much working now :)

Comment: Josh, can I be slightly cheeky, and ask one last(I promise!!!) favour? If so, I've committed several changes and can now delete items using the model.destroy method, but I can only refresh the view by calling unrender() directly from my remove method. I tried setting up events, to handle this with looser coupling, but these cannot call unrender for some reason? Cheers, and I promise to mention your great help tomorrow in a uk software meetup.

Comment: Cheers, just had a lightbulb moment understanding passing this to callbacks. I'd read that passage a couple of times today, but it just didn't sink in. Cheers for you help again! I'll now let you get on....